# return an object from socket using asynctask

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I am trying to save a Collection which I get through a socket connection. I use `AsyncTask` to read the message from socket that has the Collection. My problem is that I cannot save this message. In `OnpostExecute()` the Log.d() messages are not being displayed. If I do `ReceiveMsgAsyncTask().execute().get()` the UI freezes. I have read many similar issues but I cannot find a solution. How can I save the message received from my socket?Thanks in advance..

```
private class ReceiveMsgAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {
    final Collection <String> col = new ArrayList<String>();
    Socket socket = null ;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub;
        Object msg = null;
         try {
                socket = new Socket(host,50000);
                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                msg = in.readObject();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return msg;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("mesg","success");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        col.addAll((Collection<?extends String>)result);
    }
```

Here is the Server's method that sends the Collection to client

```
public void splitData(Master master,String client){
        int chunk=0;
        int chunckStart=0;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                String sCurrentLine;
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input"));
                int numberOflines=0;
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    numberOflines++;
                }
                br.close();
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input"));
                for (int i=1;i<=master.numberOfWorkers;i++){
                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
                    Worker Mworker = new Worker(clientsList.get(i-1));
                    if (i==master.numberOfWorkers){
                        if (numberOflines%master.numberOfWorkers!=0)
                            chunk = ((numberOflines/master.numberOfWorkers)*i)+numberOflines%master.numberOfWorkers;
                        else chunk = ((numberOflines/master.numberOfWorkers)*i);
                    }
                    else chunk = ((numberOflines/master.numberOfWorkers)*i);
                    int counter = chunk;
                    while (counter>chunckStart) {
                        sCurrentLine = br.readLine();
                        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                        //Mworker.reduce(sCurrentLine, 1);
                        Mworker.getCollection().add(sCurrentLine);
                        counter--;
                    }
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
                    chunckStart = chunckStart +(numberOflines/master.numberOfWorkers);
                    System.out.println(Mworker.getWorkerName()+" has the list:");
                    //System.out.println(Mworker.getHashReduce());
                    System.out.println(Mworker.getCollection());
                    out.writeObject(Mworker.getCollection());//send chunk to the worker/client
                    //out.flush();
                    //out.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null) br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //Mworker.hashReduce
        //}
    }
```

Comment: so is there a server sending stuff on host:50000?  If you try telnet to this can you connect?

Comment: No the connection works...The problem is that i cannot save the object that i read from the connection.(msg = in.readObject())

Comment: Your code should work if the server is sending you that object over a raw tcp socket. You should on the other hand see some kind of exception in logcat after a while. And if you do, please add that to your question.

Comment: Please post your server code.

Comment: Well it is not working though...col is empty...No i have no exceptions when i use AsyncTask.execute().
I have a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException when i use AsyncTask.execute().get(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

Comment: Have you tried hitting the debug button and looked what happens?

Comment: @zapl I prefered to use log messages to see what is going on but the log messages in async task do not display for some reason

Comment: @user2310289 The server is ok..I do not post it because it has many methods.

Comment: only interested in the writeObject part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please look at the document for [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) it clearly states

`Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.`

Therefore calling 'get' negates the whole reason to use an asynctask.

What you need to do is:

1. Create an interface with a call back method.
2. make your activity or fragment implement that interface.
3. make your ReceiveMsgAsyncTask take an object implementing that interface on it's constructor.
4. in the onPostExecute of ReceiveMsgAsyncTask call the callback method passing your results into it.

Now common pitfall here is what happens if the activity is closed or otherwise rendered defunct. This can cause crashes and all kinds of other weirdness.

The easiest way to solve that issue is to keep copies of any outstanding asynctasks and cancel then in your activities or fragments onPause methods.

Comment: 1.I created an interface with a method let's say callback()
2.I made my activity to implement that interface
3.I did not understand...AsyncTasks does not have constructor methods.Sorry but i am new to this stuff.Can you give me an example?Thanks
`public interface ReceiveInterface {
 void callback();
}`

Comment: try `public interface ReceiveInterface { void callback( Object result ); }`

Comment: My problem was on the server after all..Thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your Worker class does not implement Serialializable

See [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)

> Only objects that support the java.io.Serializable interface can be written to streams.

Comment: Well indeed my worker class did not implement Serializable.I fixed it but the problem is still there... col is empty.On the server side col is not empty.

Comment: and what about `Mworker.getCollection()`  - is your collection Serializable?

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
private Collection<? extends Serializable> dataCollection = new ArrayList<String>();